# How to create an company page like http://www.facebook.com/tapbots?

Tags: facebook

All I want is a "fan page" or "company page" like the guys over at Tapbots have got here: http://www.facebook.com/tapbots

So I clicked on to the [Create a Page for My Business](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?campaign_id=368885149649&placement=pgall&extra_1=0) Link at the bottom left of the Tapbots page. Then I registered my company there. But for some reason, even after confirmation of the email, I can't reach my company with a link like http://www.facebook.com/mycompanyname ...

any idea what's wrong? Is that some kind of special account that's hard to create?

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://www.facebook.com/username/ and select a username for your page.

It has to be unique.

It should be as close to your legal company name as possible.

Once set, it cannot be changed.

Comment: Also your page must have over 25 Likes to be eligible for a username.